# Security of the Paypal transaction ID in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, paypal, transactions

In the Paypal express payment API,

there is a field call transaction ID, it seems I only need to make sure it is unique, but the ID can be anything. So I write the code like this:

```
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
        ->setItemList($itemList)
        ->setDescription("Service Fee")
        ->setInvoiceNumber(random_string('alnum', 15));
```

The random string is function in codeigniter. But I doubt whether it is the standard way to define the ID like that:

The problems are :

1) How to define the Paypal transaction ID in PHP? e.g. using timestamp + member id ?

2) For direct payment, what should I record in Database for each transaction? The own defined transaction ID , token (the EC-xxxxxxxx one ) , amount etc...?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a Php dev, so this is more "generic":

The "transaction ID" is something to help *you* create a reference in *your* systems to a transaction.

For example, if you need to answer "was Order No. 123 paid?" (where Order 123 is something your system generates as a reference), you could search based on your *own* reference (instead of Paypal generated numbers/ids, etc.). Goes without saying that whatever you use should be something persisted in your system for it to be useful....

I wouldn't equate that to "security" however. Check the validity of the transaction details, not just some reference.

Hth.